# TSQL Running Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to show inventory levels for each day in a view. I have one table that lists the current item and quantity and another table that has all of the transactions that happened to those items. I need to create a query that lists the item, date and inventory level for that date for a trend report. Here would be some sample data in the tables:

Items:

```
ItemNumber     QuantityOnHand
----------     --------------
B34233         25.0
B34234         10.0
```

ItemTransactions:

```
TransDate      ItemNumber     Quantity
-----------    ----------     --------
1/1/2011       B34233         10.0
1/2/2011       B34234         -15.0
1/2/2011       B34233         -5.0
1/4/2011       B34234         -10.0
```

Here is the outcome I want from the query:

```
Date          ItemNumber      Quantity
----          ----------      --------
12/31/2010    B34233          20.0
12/31/2010    B34234          35.0
1/1/2011      B34233          30.0
1/1/2011      B34234          35.0
1/2/2011      B34233          25.0
1/2/2011      B34234          20.0
1/3/2011      B34233          25.0
1/3/2011      B34234          20.0
1/4/2011      B34233          25.0
1/4/2011      B34234          10.0
```

How would I write this query? I have pretty good knowledge of TSQL but cannot come up with a way to write this query.

Comment: How do you get the output from the input provided? Where is `12/31/2010` in the input?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I guess the `Items` table has the "running balance" at current time. He then wants the "history" from an arbitrary day (start day) in the past, from say `01/01/2011` up to now (or another arbitrary day). `12/31/2010` is the previous day of the "start day".

Comment: ypercude is correct. Items table has the quantity on hand at the current date (quantity that is in the warehouse right now). I need to list by day the quantity on hand at that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005` and above:

```
WITH    dates (itemNumber, quantity, currentDate, minDate) AS
        (
        SELECT  itemNumber, CAST(quantityOnHand AS DECIMAL(20, 2)), it.*
        FROM    items i
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  MAX(transDate) AS currentDate,
                        MIN(transDate) AS minDate
                FROM    itemTransactions it
                ) it
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d.itemNumber,
                CAST
                (
                d.quantity -
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  it.quantity
                FROM    itemTransactions it
                WHERE   it.transDate = d.currentDate
                        AND it.itemNumber = d.itemNumber
                ), 0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)),
                DATEADD(d, -1, currentDate),
                minDate
        FROM    dates d
        WHERE   currentDate >= minDate
        )
SELECT  currentDate, itemNumber, quantity
FROM    dates
ORDER BY
        currentDate, itemNumber
```

This assumes you have one transaction per item per day (this is a limitation of recursive `CTE` in `SQL Server`).

If you don't, you should add another `CTE` which would aggregate the transactions by day and item and use it instead of `items`:

```
WITH    itGrouped (transDate, itemNumber, quantity) AS
        (
        SELECT  transDate, itemNumber, SUM(quantity)
        FROM    itemTransactions
        GROUP BY
                transDate, itemNumber
        ),
        dates (itemNumber, quantity, currentDate, minDate) AS
        (
        SELECT  itemNumber, CAST(quantityOnHand AS DECIMAL(20, 2)), it.*
        FROM    items i
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  MAX(transDate) AS currentDate,
                        MIN(transDate) AS minDate
                FROM    itGrouped it
                ) it
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d.itemNumber,
                CAST
                (
                d.quantity -
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  it.quantity
                FROM    itGrouped it
                WHERE   it.transDate = d.currentDate
                        AND it.itemNumber = d.itemNumber
                ), 0) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)),
                DATEADD(d, -1, currentDate),
                minDate
        FROM    dates d
        WHERE   currentDate >= minDate
        )
SELECT  currentDate, itemNumber, quantity
FROM    dates
ORDER BY
        currentDate, itemNumber
```

Comment: I could have multiple records per day for one item. Should I aggregate the transactions by day in the UNION ALL -> COALESCE -> SELECT statement?

Comment: I am getting an error when I run it: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @Wili: prepend it with a semicolon: `; WITH …`.

Comment: a semicolon needs to be in front of WITH. The query works awesome on my tests. I'm gonna try it on my live data. I have a feeling it's going to take a lot of time as I have about 10,000 parts and 2 million transactions.

Answer (score 0):

See, the query is simple, but what is your requirement with date. I am giving a simple query which will give you the idea, and I am using a temporary table:

```
Create Table #Transection
(
    ID int Identity(1,1) not null,Item_Number varchar(20),Transection_Date datetime,Quantity_Available decimal(10,2)
)

insert into #Transection (Item_Number)  (Select ItemNumber from Items)

Declare @Product varchar(20),@Next_Product Cursor, @Item varchar(20),@Quantity decimal(10,2)
set  @Next_Product= CURSOR FOR Select Item_Number from #Transection open @Next_Product Fetch Next from @Next_Product into @Product

    While @@Fetch_Status=0
        Begin
            set @Item=(Select ItemNumber from  ItemTransection where ItemNumber= @Product)
                if is not null
                    Begin
                        Set @Quantity=(Select top 1 Items.Quantityonhand -ItemsTrasection.Quant as Quantity from Items Join
                                       ItemsTrasection on ItemsTrasection.ItemNumber=Items.ItemNumber where ItemsTrasection.ItemNumber=@Item order by ItemsTrasection.TransDate desc)
                        update #Transection set Transection_Date=(Select top 1 TransDate from ItemsTrasection where ItemNumber=@Item order by TransDate desc), Quantity=@Quantity
                            where Item_Number=@Item
                    End
                Else
                    Begin
                        update #Transection set Transection_Date=(Select top 1 TransDate from Items where ItemNumber=@Item ), Quantity=(Select top 1 from Items where ItemNumber=@Item )
                            where Item_Number=@Item
                    End
        End
Select * from #Transection
```

Comment: This I have made using Cursor and it will definitely work for you with minor changes.

Comment: Change ItemNumber to your Original Column Name,  ItemTransection to your Transection Table Name,Quant to your Quanity and Quantityonhand to Quantity_On_Hand Column

Comment: In case of any problem you can contact me at my email  gaurav_goel209@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 0):

A simple version using sub-select for getting quantity on hand per day.

A good / quick solution if you dont have 100k's transactions and/or a decent sql box.

Excuse the messy SQL (lunchtime coding :P )

```
CREATE TABLE #transactions (ID INT, DTE DATETIME, PROD VARCHAR(25), QTY INT )
CREATE TABLE #products (ID VARCHAR(25))
CREATE TABLE #dates (DTE DATETIME)

-- create some dates - you would do this dynamically
INSERT INTO #dates values (convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103))
INSERT INTO #dates values (convert(datetime, '02/01/2011', 103))
INSERT INTO #dates values (convert(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103))

-- create some products - you would get these from where-ever they live
INSERT INTO #products values ('A')
INSERT INTO #products values ('B')

-- create some transactions - you would get these from where-ever they live
INSERT INTO #transactions values (1, convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103), 'A', 25)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (2, convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103), 'A', -5)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (3, convert(datetime, '02/01/2011', 103), 'A', 60)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (4, convert(datetime, '02/01/2011', 103), 'A', -15)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (5, convert(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103), 'A', 100)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (6, convert(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103), 'A', -20)

INSERT INTO #transactions values (7, convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103), 'B', 10)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (8, convert(datetime, '01/01/2011', 103), 'B', 5)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (9, convert(datetime, '02/01/2011', 103), 'B', -30)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (1, convert(datetime, '02/01/2011', 103), 'B', 50)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (11, convert(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103), 'B', 10)
INSERT INTO #transactions values (12, convert(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103), 'B', 200)

-- Join dates and transactions - Do a sub select from 'begining of time' to get qty on hand per day
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), a.DTE, 103),  b.id, (SELECT sum(qty) from #transactions c where b.id = c.prod and c.DTE <= a.DTE)
FROM #dates a, #products b

-- One benefit to this approach means you can genereate qty_on_hand per days were no transactions have occured (if you needed this)

DROP TABLE #transactions
DROP TABLE #products
DROP TABLE #dates
```